# on the C language using a socket to create server and client application checks for file

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, file-exists

I know C language superficially. Actually, i need to write application using sockets client-server that verifies the existence of the file.
i have an example with sockets in which client send to server char 'A', server receive this char, increment it and send 'B' to client. client print result. i want to remake this example to my need. But it not so easy as i think, considering my knowledge.
I would really appreciate any help that you could offer me.

### client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int sockfd;
    int len;
    struct sockaddr_un address;
    int result;
    char ch='A';

    const char *filename = "/home/nikolay/test.txt";

    sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(address.sun_path, "server_socket");
    len = sizeof(address);
    result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);
    if(result == -1){
        perror("oops : client");
        exit(1);
    }

    //want to send filename to server
    write(sockfd, &filename, sizeof(filename));

    //want to receive result int value from server
    read(sockfd, &result, sizeof(result));

    if(result == 0){
        printf("file %s\t exist\n", filename);
        printf("result = %d\n", result);
    }else{
        printf("File %s\t not exist\n", filename);
        printf("result = %d\n", result);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
}
```

### server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main() {
    int server_sockfd, client_sockfd;
    int server_len, client_len;
    struct sockaddr_un server_address;
    struct sockaddr_un client_address;

    unlink("server_socket");
    server_sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    server_address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server_address.sun_path, "server_socket");
    server_len = sizeof(server_address);
    bind(server_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, server_len);

    listen(server_sockfd, 5);
    while(1) {
        char *filename;
        printf("server waiting\n");

        client_len = sizeof(client_address);
        client_sockfd = accept(server_sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len);

        //read and write client data:
        read(client_sockfd, &filename, sizeof(filename));

            // how receive access to 'filename'?
        int res = access(filename, F_OK);
        //printf("filename = %s\n", filename);
        printf("res = %d\n", res);

            //send to client result check exist file
        write(client_sockfd, &res, sizeof(res));
        close(client_sockfd);
    }
}
```

How i can send to server file's name (string), than server receive this string, check is this file exist and send result (int value) to the client?

Some changes, using recv and send.

### client

```
send(sockfd, filename, strlen(filename), 0);

    printf("client: send\n");
    char* res;
    recv(sockfd, res, strlen(res), 0);
    printf("client: reseive\n");
    if(strcasecmp(res, "1") == 0){
        printf("file %s\t exist\n", filename);
    }else if(strcasecmp(res, "-1") == 0){
        printf("file %s\t not exist\n", filename);
    }
```

### server:

```
recv(client_sockfd, filename, strlen(filename), 0);
        int res = access(filename, F_OK);
        //printf("filename = %s\n", filename);
        printf("res = %d\n", res);

        //write(client_sockfd, &res, sizeof(res));
        char* buffer;
        snprintf (buffer, 10, "%d", res);
        printf("convert to string: %s\n", buffer);
        printf("buffer len: %d\n", strlen(buffer));
        send(client_sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer),0);
```

occured Segmentation fault error. Why did this can happened? Console:

```
./client
client: send
res = -1
convert to string: -1
buffer len: 2
client: reseive
[1]+  Segmentation fault      ./server
```

Comment: is there a reason for posting the source twice?

Comment: first is the working example, second - my not working attempt)

Comment: You might like to add error checking on all (relevant) system calls.

Comment: Closely read the man-pages for read()/write() and learn that at least for sockets those two functions do not necessarily receive/send as much bytes as they were told to, but few. So looping around such calls counting until all data had been received/sent is a good idea, not to say an essential necessity.

Answer (score 0):

> Some changes, using recv and send.
>
> ```
>   char* res;
>   recv(sockfd, res, strlen(res), 0);
> ```
>
> occured Segmentation fault error. Why did this can happened?

`res` is not initialized, its value is indeterminate. Yet using this indeterminate value as an argument to `strlen()` is faulty. Let's discard the failed changes and get your *working example* to work.

> ### client:
>
> ```
>   const char *filename = "/home/nikolay/test.txt";
> … 
>   //want to send filename to server
>   write(sockfd, &filename, sizeof(filename));
> ```

Here not the file name characters are sent, but a pointer to them, which is meaningless in the address space of the server. Simple fix:

```
    const char filename[] = "/home/nikolay/test.txt";
```

### server:

```
        #include <limits.h>
        char filename[PATH_MAX];
```

The comment from [alk Dec 28 '13 at 15:21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812874/on-the-c-language-using-a-socket-to-create-server-and-client-application-checks#comment31212700_20812874) is also noteworthy.